# Unable to deploy postgres/react application to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, debugging, heroku, deployment

I've been stuck for awhile now and I can't seem to figure out what the bug is. Deploying my application to to Heroku, the build succeeds and I'm getting back static files, but the problem is the apps inability to connect to the Heroku sql server. These are the current bugs i'm getting.

```
2021-02-19T21:59:42.585708+00:00 app[web.1]: Alright you got it! running on 37052
2021-02-19T21:59:42.615527+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to prune sessions: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined
2021-02-19T22:01:17.248861+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined
2021-02-19T22:01:17.248874+00:00 app[web.1]: at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
2021-02-19T22:01:17.248876+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -3008,
2021-02-19T22:01:17.248878+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ENOTFOUND',
2021-02-19T22:01:17.248878+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
2021-02-19T22:01:17.248879+00:00 app[web.1]: hostname: 'undefined'
2021-02-19T22:01:17.248879+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

This is my server.js file.

```
const express = require(`express`);
const passport = require(`passport`);
const session = require(`express-session`);
const postGresqlStore = require("connect-pg-simple")(session);
const keys = require("./config/keys");
const usersRouter = require(`./src/routes/users`);
const flash = require(`connect-flash`);

const initializePassport = require("./passportConfig");
initializePassport(passport);

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  session({
    store: new postGresqlStore({
      conString: `postgres://${keys.DB_USER}:${keys.DB_PASSWORD}@${keys.DB_HOST}:${keys.DB_PORT}/${keys.DB_DATABASE}`,
    }),
    secret: keys.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
  })
);
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(usersRouter);

const path = require("path");
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Serve any static files
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  // Handle React routing, return all requests to React app
  app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Alright you got it! running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

and my DB.config

```
const keys = require(`./config/keys`);

const { Pool } = require("pg");

const devConfig = `postgres://${keys.DB_USER}:${keys.DB_PASSWORD}@${keys.DB_HOST}:${keys.DB_PORT}/${keys.DB_DATABASE}`;
const proConfig = process.env.DATABASE_URL;

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString:
    process.env.NODE.ENV === `production` ? proConfig : devConfig,
});

module.exports = { pool };
```

Any suggestions or other parts of the code that need to be viewed?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you add all your .env variables to heroku?? Like DATABASE_URL? I could be wrong but I also have never used process.env.NODE.ENV. heroku looks for this instead, so maybe try this.

process.env.NODE_ENV

Comment: The DATABASE_URL was provided by heroku, so its already in the .env variables. I checked it multiple times. Thanks for pointing that out in the db.config. Ill updated it and see if I have any luck

Comment: unfortunately, I'm still getting a ```Failed to prune sessions: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined.```. I wonder if there is something wrong with the way I'm using express session?

Comment: I also just realized that I had the same type-o in my server.js file too... I just fixed it. Hopefully something happens.

Comment: Did that fix it??

Comment: it did! I can't believe i was stuck so long on that... Now I'm getting another error... something to do with the SSL certificate. Thank you!

Comment: Great! It's usually something simple that get's me stuck the longest as well.

Comment: I added an answer, so if you feel like it solved the question accept it please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use process.env.NODE_ENV in your db.config. It's the default set by heroku.